# SoundPool | Check stream whether it is playing or not

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, soundpool

I am using soundpool to play short audio files . Once I click the button it should play audio and second time it should pause stream . I used function like this `detectPlayPause(sound2, activity!!.applicationContext)`
The problem is it is not pausing and it is playing that sound again as a two stream

```html
fun detectPlayPause(sound: Int, context: Context) {
        val audioManager = context.getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
        if (audioManager.isStreamMute(sound)) {
            soundPool.play(sound, 1F, 1F, 0, -1, 1F)
        } else {
            soundPool.pause(sound)
        }}
```

**

Answer (score 0):

You're mis-using `audioManager.isStreamMute()`. That function takes an `AudioManager` constant, like `STREAM_MUSIC`. That is a different thing than the sound ID returned from `SoundPool.load()`.

`isStreamMute()` won't tell you whether or not your sound is playing. That's more for detecting the device's mute settings; whether the user has selected mute/vibrate/silent, etc.

Instead, just track your play state using a boolean variable.

```
if (!playing) {
    playing = true
    soundPool.play(sound, 1F, 1F, 0, -1, 1F)
} else {
    playing = false
    soundPool.pause(sound)
}
```